# Alphabetize rows in a CSV File in Python

Tags: python, r, sorting, alphabetical

I have a CSV file which was generated from a list of words similar to the following

```
moth
dog
zebra
elephant
yak
horse
ant
moose
snake
walrus
lion
turtle
kangaroo
```

I need to sort this list alphabetically. What is the best way to do that?

I tried putting this list into a CSV file and reading past Stack Overflow treads on sorting CSV files in Python. However, these strategies do not seem to work.

Please note that the solution does not need to be in Python, it can also be in R.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show some code? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html what is your end goal? You can do this in Excel (or google sheets) with no code at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sorted/sort depending on your need. For string it will sort lexicographically. Below is the example

```
sorted("""moth
dog
zebra
elephant
yak
horse
ant
moose
snake
walrus
lion
turtle
kangaroo""".split())
```